# Memory leak in WPF tab window

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have WPF .Net 4 project in which there is a problem with memory leak. After investigation i found that problem in window with tabs.

Data in tabs presented as View and there are 2 types of views (Type1View and Type2View). After changing of selected item from type1 to type2 (or opposite) constructor of view is called. I think there is root of problem, because memory consumption is increased after that, but isn't cleared after tab closing. I tried to use GC.Collect, but it didn't help. Can you advise me, how to solve the problem?

Code of test project with tab window realization (without tab closing) below:

**XAML of tab window:**

```
<Window x:Class="TestApp.Views.TypesViewTabWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="TypesViewTabWindow" Height="294" Width="520">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDictionaries\TabDictionary.xaml" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <TabControl IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Workspaces}"
                Margin="4" 
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                Background="White" >
        <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding ElementName=ContentSite, Path=ActualWidth}" />
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsActive}" />
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource TabItemStyle}" />
            </Style>
        </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </TabControl>
</Window>
```

**Resource dictionary of tab window:**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:TestApp.ViewModels" xmlns:View="clr-namespace:TestApp.Views"
                xmlns:gif="http://wpfanimatedgif.codeplex.com">

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:Type1AgregateViewModel}" x:Shared="False">
    <View:Type1View />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:Type2AgregateViewModel}" x:Shared="False">
    <View:Type2View />
</DataTemplate>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="TabItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Grid x:Name="gr">
        <Border Name="Border" Background="#F0F0F0" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" CornerRadius="4,4,0,0" Margin="-2,0,3,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" >

            <Grid Margin="10,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="15" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="15" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock ToolTip="{Binding Path=Name}" MaxWidth="135" x:Name="TextBlock" Margin="10,5,10,5" FontSize="15" Foreground="DarkGray" Grid.Column="1"
                           Text="{Binding Path=Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

**ViewModel of tab window:**

```
public class TypesViewTabViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly Dispatcher _currentDispatcher;

    public TypesViewTabViewModel()
    {
        _currentDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// workspace for the tabs
    /// </summary>
    private ObservableCollection<AbstractWorkspaceViewModel> _workspaces;

    /// <summary>
    /// workspace for the tabs
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<AbstractWorkspaceViewModel> Workspaces
    {
        get
        {
            if (_workspaces == null)
            {
                _workspaces = new ObservableCollection<AbstractWorkspaceViewModel>();
            }
            return _workspaces;
        }
    }

    public void AddNewWorkspace(AbstractWorkspaceViewModel newWorkspace)
    {
        if (newWorkspace == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("newWorkspace");

        var viewModel = newWorkspace as IIdentifier;

        try
        {
            AbstractWorkspaceViewModel workspace;
            if (viewModel != null)
            {
                var taskAgregateViewModels = Workspaces.OfType<IIdentifier>().ToList();
                workspace = (AbstractWorkspaceViewModel)taskAgregateViewModels.Where(t => ((t.Id == viewModel.Id) && (t.GetType() == viewModel.GetType()))).FirstOrDefault();
                if (workspace == null)
                {
                    workspace = (AbstractWorkspaceViewModel) newWorkspace.Clone();
                    Workspaces.Add(workspace);
                }
            }
            else
            {

                workspace = (AbstractWorkspaceViewModel)newWorkspace.Clone();

                var indexWorkspace = Workspaces.IndexOf(workspace);

                if (indexWorkspace < 0) Workspaces.Add(workspace);
            }

            SetActiveWorkspace(workspace);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }

    private void SetActiveWorkspace(AbstractWorkspaceViewModel workspace)
    {
        if (workspace == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("workspace");

        var collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Workspaces);

        if (collectionView == null) return;

        collectionView.MoveCurrentTo(workspace);

        collectionView.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Other views and viewmodels contains only constructor and some fields. Full example project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/y2awoul21wekphw/TestApp.zip?dl=0

Comment: Are you binding models (that are no viewmodels, read: do not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`) to the view?

Comment: @Tseng ViewModel inherited from ViewModelBase in library GalaSoft.MvvmLight. ViewModelBase has realization `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `INotifyPropertyChanging`.

Comment: Right, but in your XAML you have a `Name` binding and it's not in the viewmodel posted, so is that from another ViewModel or from some model. I ask because binding classes, that do not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface can cause memory leaks too

Comment: @Tseng Workspaces viewmodel also inherited from ViewModelBase. I just don't post it, because it have small amount of code, you can see it in full project.

Comment: 1. Why do you believe that there is a memory leak? Have you run a memory profiler on your app inspecting the surviving objects up to the GC-roots? 2. How much memory does your app "leak"?

Comment: @dymanoid Original big application consumed too much memory at long run (problem was found, when application consumed 2GB). I used dotMemory and found that memory leak is in tab window - consumed memory of that element increased, when i opened tabs, but not fully cleared, when i closed the tabs.

Comment: So if you have a memory profiler, then it should be very easy to find out which objects survive or become "zombies".

Comment: In future, if you're going to dump a ton of code into your question, take a minute and clear out all the unimportant stuff.  As in, `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"` is completely inconsequential, yet it's taking up a whole line.  Keeping your example code compact makes it easier to read and parse.

Comment: @dymanoid Yes, i find out these survive objects and as i said in my question it's views in tab window (Type1View and Type2View in test project).

Comment: @Will you are assuming the asker knows what is important.

Comment: @Gusdor if he can't figure out that this question has nothing to do with content alignment, he's got more issues than a memory leak.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. You've found out what objects survive and which references prevent them from being GC'ed. So you have the answer already: just make sure the references get `null`'ed to let your objects vanish.

Comment: @dymanoid Constructors of these objects are called from external code and I can't figure out, from which reference it is comes and why.